# How to change background color on condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I am using following style to show div in my page as even odd combination:
css:

```
.task-container:nth-child(even) {
    background: none;
}

.task-container:nth-child(odd) {
    background: rgba(2, 104, 144, .05);
}

.timeout {
    background-color: #ffc;
}
```

In HTML. I am using `div` in `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="task-container">
    ... other divs
</div>
```

With some conditions i want to change the background color like yellow but it is not working as nth-child(even)/odd overriding the yellow color. I tried something like that:

```
<div class="task-container" data-ng-class="{'timeout': alarm.timeOutOccured== true}">
```

Can someone help me to find a correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `.timeout` class is being added properly on your `div` element, you just need to add the `!important` in your CSS:

```
.timeout {
    background-color: #ffc !important;
}
```

This is because, the `.task-container:nth-child(even)` or `.task-container:nth-child(odd)` is more specific so it will get higher priority.

Also, it is not recommended to use `!important` so you can write more specific selector like this (and you don't need `!important` flag):

```
.task-container.timeout {
    background-color: #ffc;
}
```

See a simplified example below:

```css
.task-container:nth-child(even) {
  background: none;
}
.task-container:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(2, 104, 144, .05);
}
.task-container.timeout {
  background-color: #ffc;
}
```

```html
<div class="task-container">
1
</div>
<div class="task-container">
2
</div>
<div class="task-container timeout">
3
</div>
<div class="task-container">
4
</div>
<div class="task-container">
5
</div>
<div class="task-container">
6
</div>
<div class="task-container timeout">
7
</div>
```

Comment: How about adding a more-specific class? I wouldn't suggest using !important, which can only be overridden by another !important css style

Comment: Thanks @Max I was just updating that

Comment: more specific means: task-container.is-timeout { background-color: #ffc }